# Fredholm integral equation, exercise 12 Functional analysis Kreyszig

Tags: functional-analysis, integral-equations

I'm trying to do a exercise of Kreyszig book of functional analysis but I'm stuck, I'm trying to solve the integral equation
\begin{equation}
   x(s)-\mu \int_{0}^{2\pi}sin(s)cos(t)x(t)dt =\hat{y}(s)
\end{equation}
Where $\hat{y}$ is a given function in $C[0,2\pi]$.

My attempt consist of define $\displaystyle Tx(s):=\int_{0}^{2\pi}sin(s)cos(t)x(t)dt$, and note that if we take $\lambda>2\pi$ where $\lambda=\frac{1}{\mu}$ then $\|\frac{T}{\lambda}\|<1$ so $(I-\frac{T}{\lambda})^{-1}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{(\frac{T}{\lambda})^{i}}$ and then easyly we get a solution but what occurs if $\lambda\leq 2\pi$?

Comment: The operator $T$ is one dimensional. It is of the form $(Tx)(s)=\langle x,\cos t\rangle \,\sin s.$

Comment: What is $\hat{y}(s)$? What is $\lambda$?

Comment: @Gonçalo $\hat{y}$ is a given function and $\lambda=\frac{1}{\mu}$

Comment: $\mu$? the range of $\mu$?

Comment: @monotoneoperator the exercise is very ambiguous, I'm assuming that $\mu$ is only a given real non zero but really the exercise does not saying noting about $\mu$

Comment: Observe that $x-\widehat{y}$ is a multiple of $\sin s.$ Hence $x=\widehat{y} + a\sin s.$ Plug it into the equation and you will be able to solve it.